# this.router.navigate() doesn't navigate to the URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a pagination demo application in Angular. I am expecting to be able to navigate to a URL like `http://localhost:4200/page/:number`. The URL appears to be changing in the browser's URL address bar but I have to press Enter key on the browser's URL address bar in order to actually navigate to the URL and have the data change on the HTML table.

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-225jrs (`HttpErrorResponse` is not part of the question, but I don't know how to fix that in Stackblitz). Here is my code:

page.component.html:

```
<span *ngFor="let x of fakeArray; let index = index">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goToPage(index)">{{ index + 1 }}</button>
</span>

<br><br>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Alue-ID</th>
      <th>Kunta</th>
      <th>Lääni</th>
      <th>Maakunta</th>
      <th>Seutukunta</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let municipality of municipalities">
      <td>{{ municipality.alue_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ municipality.kunta }}</td>
      <td>{{ municipality.laani }}</td>
      <td>{{ municipality.maakunta }}</td>
      <td>{{ municipality.seutukunta }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<span *ngFor="let x of fakeArray; let index = index">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goToPage(index)">{{ index + 1 }}</button>
</span>

<br><br>
```

page.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MunicipalitiesService } from '../municipalities.service';
import { municipality } from '../municipality.interface';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.css']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  municipalities: municipality[] = [];
  pagenumber: number;
  fakeArray: any;

  constructor(
    private service: MunicipalitiesService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.pagenumber = +params.number;
    })

    this.service.getOneHundredRecords(this.pagenumber).then((data: municipality[]) => {
      this.municipalities = data;
    });

    this.service.getPageCount().then((pageCount: number) => {
      this.fakeArray = new Array(pageCount);
    })
  }

  goToPage = (index: number) => {
    this.router.navigate([`/page/${index}`]);
  }

}
```

municipalities.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { municipality } from './municipality.interface';

@Injectable()
export class MunicipalitiesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOneHundredRecords = (page: number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get("/assets/data.json").subscribe((data: municipality[]) => {
        let municipalities = data;
        let index = 0;
        let toBeReturned: municipality[] = [];

        for (let municipality of municipalities) {
          if (index >= (page * 100) && index < (page + 1) * 100) {
            toBeReturned.push(municipality);
          }
          index++;
        }
        resolve(toBeReturned)
      })
    })
  }

  getPageCount = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
      this.http.get("/assets/data.json").subscribe((data: municipality[]) => {
        let municipalities = data;
        let index = 0;

        for (let municipality of municipalities) {
          index++;
        }

        let pageCount = Math.ceil(index / 100);
        resolve(pageCount)
      })
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Technically you are still in the same route to the same component, thus it doesn't reload. You can force the reload by doing this: `this.router.navigate([`/page/${index}`]).then(() => window.location.reload());` however i'd advise doing this because it basically removed all your states. So instead of doing `navigate` it is better if you grab your new set data via `goToPage()` method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a policy with Angular router that prevents you when you want to navigate to the same route from the one that you are currently in.
You could use RouteReuseStrategy like this:

page.component.ts:

```
***

constructor() {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}

***
```

This will allow your component to refresh after you navigate on her (from her).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You saved me, it took me about two days to make it working!
But now modal window opens twice. But perhaps it's some of our application bugs.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: Maaan... I spent over 13 hours trying to make it work and when I was going to give up I found your solution and it worked! Thanks a lot!!!